# find if the xss injection bypassed the filter from python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xss

I'm writing a crawler, (in python 2.7, windows 10) that receive an address of a web page (like https://www.wikipedia.com ) and crawle to find all the pages.
once this is done the program should go on all the pages and try to find an xss vulnerability, my problem is that after injecting the payload I don't know how to verify if the attack succeeded or not (verifying if the payload is in the page isn't good enough because some filter could have changed the payload - without really disabling this. a good example is the payload `<scrip<script>t>alert(0)</sc</script>ript>` this payload NEEDS the filter to change it in order to work...)

my question is how can I find if an alert (for example) will pop (and if possible without new modules that need to be installed).

thanks!

Comment: This has absolutely  nothing directly to do with javascript so am removing that tag. Please try tagging according to relevance to actual problem

Comment: @charlietfl the tag is because one of the solutions is running javascrip in python... (to find if the alert shows)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium and `switch_to.alert()` to identify the successful invocation of alert.

Comment: thanks, but from what I see (correct me if I'm wrong) selenium need to use the browser to go to the pages and to execute them, but this will far take too much time to do for an entire site...

Comment: It will take relatively more time, yes.